# Bug: "Unspecified error" some of the time in IE11 in iframe

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Open http://cygnetuat.sterlingdatarooms.com/PDFTronClientTest/ in IE11
2. Wait for the application to load in the iframe
   The current behavior
   Sometimes an "Unspecified error" will appear in the console and the viewer in the iframe won't load

[image]

Unfortunately, it is not 100% reproducible. Sometimes the error won't occur. I'm also having trouble creating a minimal sample to reproduce this.

The expected behavior
There is no error.

Comment: The [site](http://cygnetuat.sterlingdatarooms.com/PDFTronClientTest/) looks like a product of [sterlingdatarooms](https://www.sterlingvdr.com/).I noticed that error will also occur if you directly open that site in the IE browser. It is better to contact that site for the solution to this issue. Without any code sample, it will be hard for us to get an idea about the cause of the issue. Thanks for your understanding.